# Upgrading elasticsearch from 0.20.5 to 0.90.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 5 node 0.20.5 Elasticsearch cluster, with replicas set to 2, shards set to 5 and around 70 Million documents that I would like to upgrade to 0.90.0

I can't seem to find definitive instructions for upgrading, I was thinking
something along these lines:

1. Issue cluster shutdown:

   `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/nodes/_local/_shutdown'`
2. Upgrade each of the nodes using the 0.90.0 deb package

   `dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.20.5.deb`
3. Start elasticsearch on each of the nodes:

   `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start`

Should I look at changing any of these settings prior?

`gateway.recover_after_nodes`

`gateway.recover_after_time`

`gateway.expected_nodes`

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't get any responses so I backed up all the nodes and tried the above and it worked a treat!